# asp.net core page not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have error "Page not found" on my website.

This is what i have came up with.

- Error occurred to clients few times without me knowing exact moment
- When i tested it it ALWAYS happens when i restart my website asp.net server but under some circumstances which i will describe later
- It happens in some controllers but in some not
- It happens only until i open some controller that will load website, then all other works too.
- It happens only on published website and not in my local environment.

So first line is clear and doesn't need explanation.

Second line:
    What i have tested to get this error is i shut down my server and then start it again. After it i try going to `mywebsite.com/User` and error comes.

Third line:
   It only happens in controllers `/User` and `/Kalkulator` but not in `/` or `/Proizvodi`

Forth line:
   When i open controller `/User` and refresh it multiple times it doesn't load but when i go to `/` and then to `/User` it loads.

Here are my controllers with their views. I will only provide `/User` and `/Kalkulator` since there is easiest to see what happens.

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //Debug log are control lines that write to my txt file but they are never reached on first time going to this controller, but when i do fourth step they do reach.
        Debug.Log(null, "User/Index pocetak", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
        try
        {
            Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Checking isLogged", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);

            if (Networking.IsLogged(Request))
            {
                Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Checking isAdmin", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
                if (Networking.IsAdmin(Request))
                {
                    Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Return redirect admin", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
                    return Redirect("/Admin?select=POR");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Return redirect /Proizvodi", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
                    return Redirect("/Proizvodi");
                }
            }
            Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Creting new user class", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);

            AR.TDShop.User u = new AR.TDShop.User();
                    Debug.Log(null, "User/Index Return view with user class", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
            return View(u);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Log(null, "User/Index catch error", Debug.Type.CasualChange, Request);
            return View("Error", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

User View

```
@model AR.TDShop.User
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Profi kutak";
}


<style>
    #Login {
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        width: 400px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 100px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

        #Login input {
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 30px;
            width: 60%;
        }

        #Login button {
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 18px;
            border: none;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }

            #Login button:hover {
                background-color: #ff4d4d;
            }

    #PostaniClan button:hover {
        background-color: lawngreen !important;
        color: black !important;
    }
</style>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div id="Login">
        <p style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; color: white; background-color: red; font-weight: bolder; font-size: x-large">Logovanje</p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @placeholder = "username" })
        <br />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PW, new { @placeholder = "password", @type = "password" })
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Potvrdi</button>
    </div>
}
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom: 30px" id="PostaniClan">
    <button onclick="window.location.href='/Majstori/Registracija'" style="background-color: green; color: white; border-radius: 20px; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;">Postani član!</button>
</div>
}
```

As you can see in `user` controller/view there are few other commands that are not shown here but i think you do not need them and you will get it when you take a look at `/Kalkulator` controller which also doesn't works and here it is:

```
   public class KalkulatorController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and here is the view:

```
@{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Kalkulator";
    }
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="card bg-info text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">GKP - Plafon</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Izracunajte utrosak materijala koji Vam je potreban za izradu spustenog plafona u gips karton sistemu.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Izracunaj!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-info text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">GKP - Zid (oblaganje)</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Izracunajte utrosak materijala koji Vam je potreban za oblaganje postojeceg zida.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Izracunaj!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-info text-center" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">GKP - Zid (pregradjivanje)</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Izracunajte utrosak materijala koji Vam je potreban za izradu novog pregradnog zida.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Izracunaj!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see it is pure HTML and it doesn't work....

Here is my `/Proizvodi` controller which works (it has a lot of commands so i will display only index and view)

```
public IActionResult Index(int? GrupaID, int? PodgrupaID, int? V, string Pretraga)
    {
        ProizvodiModel pm = new ProizvodiModel(GrupaID, PodgrupaID, V, Request);
        pm.Tag = Pretraga;
        return View(pm);
    }
```

VIEW:

```
@model ProizvodiModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Proizvodi";
    List<Tuple<int, double>> CeneZaKorisnika = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();
    if (Networking.IsLogged(Context.Request))
    {
        CeneZaKorisnika = AR.TDShop.User.GetVPCene(Model.User.UserID);
        CeneZaKorisnika.Sort((x, y) => x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1));
    }
    if (!Model.Majstor)
    {
        <style>
            .proizvod {
                margin-bottom: 5px !important;
            }
        </style>
    }
    else
    {
        <style>
            .proizvod {
                margin-bottom: 103px !important;
            }
        </style>
    }
}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/ProizvodiIndex.css" />
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div id="left" class="col-sm-3" style=" color: white">
        <div style="width: 100%; margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 40px; text-align: center">
            <img src="~/images/Logo_Long.png" style="width: 90%;" />
        </div>
        @if (Model.Majstor)
        {
            Model.User.UcitajPorudzbine(Context.Request);

            if (Model.User.Porudzbine.Count > 0)
            {
                <div style="background-color: red; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center; margin: 0;">Skorašnje porudžbine</h3>
                    @{
                        int n = 5;
                        <table id="PorudzbineTable" style="width: 100%;margin-top: 10px; background-color: #ffbbbb; color: black">
                            @foreach (AR.TDShop.Porudzbina p in Model.User.Porudzbine)
                            {
                                <tr onclick="window.location.href='/Porudzbina?ID=' + @p.PorudzbinaID">
                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px">@p.BrDokKom</td>
                                    @switch (p.Status)
                                    {
                                        case AR.TDShop.Porudzbina.PorudzbinaStatus.NaObradi:
                                            <td>Na obradi!</td>
                                            break;
                                        case AR.TDShop.Porudzbina.PorudzbinaStatus.CekaUplatu:
                                            <td>Čeka uplatu!</td>
                                            break;
                                        case AR.TDShop.Porudzbina.PorudzbinaStatus.ZaPreuzimanje:
                                            <td>Za preuzimanje!</td>
                                            break;
                                        case AR.TDShop.Porudzbina.PorudzbinaStatus.Preuzeto:
                                            <td>Realizovano!</td>
                                            break;
                                        case AR.TDShop.Porudzbina.PorudzbinaStatus.Stornirana:
                                            <td>Stornirano!</td>
                                            break;
                                    }
                                </tr>

                                n--;
                                if (n <= 0)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        </table>
                        <button id="SvePorudzbine" onclick="window.location.href='/User/Porudzbine'" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 10px; background-color: white; color: black">Sve porudzbine</button>
                    }
                </div>
            }
            <div id="ObjasnjenjeCene">
                <p>Cena bez PDV-a je iskazana crvenom bojom!</p>
            </div>
        }
        <div style="padding: 15px; background-color: #5a5cd4; margin-bottom: 40px">
            <button class="@if (@Model.ActivateGrupa == null && Model.ActivatePodgrupa == null) { @Html.Raw("activate") }" onclick="GoTo('/Proizvodi')">Svi proizvodi</button>


            @foreach (GrupaModel g in Model.Grupe)
            {
                <button class="@if (Model.ActivateGrupa != null && Model.ActivateGrupa == g.GrupaID)
                {
                    @Html.Raw("activate")
                } else if (@Model.ActivatePodgrupa != null)
                {
                    if(PodgrupaModel.GetParent((int)Model.ActivatePodgrupa) == g.GrupaID) { @Html.Raw("activate") }
                }"
                        onclick="GoTo('/Proizvodi?GrupaID=@g.GrupaID')">
                    @g.Naziv
                </button>
            }
        </div>
        <div id="PredloziProizvod" style="border-top: black 2px; color: black;">
            <button id="predloziButton" style="width: 100%; text-align: center">Predloži proizvod</button>
            <input hidden type="text" placeholder="Naziv proizvoda" />
            <input hidden type="text" placeholder="Kataloski broj" />
            <input hidden type="text" placeholder="Opis primene" />
            <button hidden id="PosaljiPredlogProizvoda">Posalji</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="col-sm-9">

        <div id="PretragaProizvoda">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pretraga..." value="@Model.Tag" />
            <button id="tw" style="float: right" onclick="ToggleView(this)" value="0"><img src="~/images/View2.png" style="width: 25px" /></button>
        </div>
        <br />
        @if (Model.PodGrupe.Count > 0)
        {
            string cls = "";
            if (Model.ActivatePodgrupa == null)
            {
                cls = "aktivnaPodgrupa";
            }
            <div id="PodGrupe">
                <button class="PodGrupa @cls" onclick="GoTo('/Proizvodi?GrupaID=@PodgrupaModel.GetParent((int)Model.PodGrupe[0].PodgrupaID))'">
                    <p>Svi proizvodi grupe</p>
                </button>
                @foreach (PodgrupaModel pgm in Model.PodGrupe)
                {
                    cls = "";
                    if (pgm.PodgrupaID == Model.ActivatePodgrupa)
                    {
                        cls = "aktivnaPodgrupa";
                    }
                    <button class="PodGrupa @cls" onclick="GoTo('/Proizvodi?PodgrupaID=@pgm.PodgrupaID')">
                        <p>@pgm.Naziv</p>
                    </button>
                }
            </div>
            <hr style="border-bottom: 2px solid black" />
        }
        @foreach (ProizvodModel p in Model.Proizvodi)
        {
            if (p.Aktivan)
            {
                string proizvodStil;
                string buttonStil;

                if (p.Klasifikacija == 0)
                {
                    proizvodStil = "color: dimgray;";
                    buttonStil = "background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, dimgray 20%, dimgray 80%, white 100%);";
                }
                else if (p.Klasifikacija == 2)
                {
                    proizvodStil = "color: darkorange;";
                    buttonStil = "background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, darkorange 20%, darkorange 80%, white 100%);";
                }
                else
                {
                    proizvodStil = "color: darkgreen;";
                    buttonStil = "background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, darkgreen 20%, darkgreen 80%, white 100%);";
                }

                <div class="proizvod ppppp @if (Model.Majstor) { @Html.Raw("korpa"); } normal"
                     @Html.Raw("onclick = \"GoToP('" + @p.ROBAID + "')\"") ;
                     style="@proizvodStil">
                    <p class="katBr">@p.KatBr</p>
                    <img src="@p.Slika" />
                    <p class="nazivProizvoda">@p.Naziv</p>
                    @if (Model.Majstor)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int NivoZaKorisnika = Model.User.Cenovnik_grupa.Where(x => x.Item1 == p.Cenovnik_GrupaID).Select(t => t.Item2).FirstOrDefault();
                            double VPCena = CeneZaKorisnika.Where(x => x.Item1 == p.ROBAID).FirstOrDefault().Item2;
                            double MPCena = VPCena + (VPCena * p.PDV / 100);

                            if (MPCena > 0)
                            {
                                <p class="vpcena">@VPCena.ToString("#,###.00") / @p.JM</p>
                                <p class="mpcena">@MPCena.ToString("#,###.00") / @p.JM</p>
                                if (Model.User.Vrsta == UserModel.Tip.Majstor)
                                {
                                    <button style="@buttonStil" onclick="GoToP(@p.ROBAID); event.stopPropagation();"> KUPI!</button>
                                }
                            }
                            if (Model.User.Vrsta == UserModel.Tip.Administrator)
                            {
                                <button style="@buttonStil" onclick="Edit(@p.ROBAID); event.stopPropagation();">Detalji!</button>
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            @:alert("@ex.ToString()");
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>

<div id="AlertPopUp">
</div>
<script src="~/js/AlertBox.js"></script>
<script>

    var alb = new AlertBox($("#AlertPopUp"));


    var currRID = -1;
    var overwrite = false;

    function GoTo(link) {
        if ($("#tw").val() == 1) {
            if (link.indexOf('?') > -1) {
                window.location.href = link + "&V=1";
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = link + "?V=1";
            }
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = link;
        }
    }

    function GoToP(link) {
        if ($("#tw").val() == 1) {
            if (link.indexOf('?') > -1) {
                window.location.href = link + "&V=1";
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = link + "?V=1";
            }
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "/Proizvod?ID=" + link;
        }
    }

    function Edit(id) {
        GoTo("/Proizvodi/Edit?ID=" + id);
    }

    function ToggleView(element) {
        var curr = $(element).val();
        if (curr == 1) {
            $(element).val(0);
            $(element).children("img").attr("src", "/images/View2.png");
            $(".ppppp").removeClass("proizvod1");
            $(".ppppp").addClass("block");
            $(".ppppp").addClass("proizvod");
            $(".korpa button").html("Dodaj u korpu!");
        }
        else {
            $(element).val(1);
            $(element).children("img").attr("src", "/images/View1.png");
            $(".ppppp").removeClass("proizvod");
            $(".ppppp").removeClass("block");
            $(".ppppp").addClass("proizvod1");
            $(".korpa button").html("<img src='/Images/cart.png' style='height: 50px;width: 50px;border-radius: 10px;padding: 5px;padding-right: 8px;background-color: #2196F3;' />");
        }
    }

    @{
        if(Model.View == 1)
        {
            @:StartOtherView();
        }
    }

    function StartOtherView() {
        $("#tw").val(1);
        $("#tw").children("img").attr("src", "/images/View1.png");
        $(".ppppp").removeClass("proizvod");
        $(".ppppp").removeClass("block");
        $(".ppppp").addClass("proizvod1");
        $(".korpa button").html("<img src='/Images/cart.png' style='height: 50px;width: 50px;border-radius: 10px;padding: 5px;padding-right: 8px;background-color: #2196F3;' />");
    }

    $(function () {
        var PredloziProizvodBlock = false;
        $("#predloziButton").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("input").each(function () {
                if (PredloziProizvodBlock == true) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
            if (PredloziProizvodBlock == true) {
                $("#PosaljiPredlogProizvoda").hide();
            }
            else {
                $("#PosaljiPredlogProizvoda").show();
            }
            PredloziProizvodBlock = !PredloziProizvodBlock;
        })

        $("#PosaljiPredlogProizvoda").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Proizvodi/PosaljiPredlogProizvoda",
                contentType: "application.json; charset-utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        })

        $("#PretragaProizvoda input").keyup(function () {
            var input = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
            $(".proizvod").each(function () {
                if ($(this).html().toUpperCase().indexOf(input) >= 0 || input.length == 0) {
                    $(this).show();
                }
                else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

All views use same layout.

Routing option:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: When you get the error by going to `mywebsite.com/User`, is that still the address in the url bar? It hasn't redirected anywhere else?

Comment: Yeah it is same

Comment: Do you have any middleware that might be interrupting the pipeline based on something like authorization/authentication or some value that is cached by the other controller methods that work before these ones do? Which then allows it to work for the others?

Comment: I think i found mistake.... updating in few minutes just to test it....

Comment: Okay, I might have accessed the site as it restarted this time though on the home url... Not sure - Sorry :)

Comment: Did you get it right? Out of curiosity, what was the issue?

Comment: Take a look at answer. It will also help you someday since no one told me that i haven't posted all code and only that sentence would solve problem :)

Comment: Cool then I think I helped out :) You can also look at having that kind of functionality in a `Middleware` component, which you add to the request pipeline, and then it gets executed on every request so that it's always done and you don't have to remember to add it to your constructors and is more DRY. 
Doing that also means you don't have to inject `IHostingEnvironment` into all your controllers.

Comment: Yea thank you. I was going to research about that possibility since i thought it exists and now you pointed me out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem with `Redirect` in you UserController, could your try replace it on `RedirectToAction()`; It's must be help you.

Comment: I will try it but look at `Kalkulator` controller which returns plain `view` and still not working...

Comment: `RedirectToAction();` did not work on `UserController`

Answer (score 0):

I found out mistake and it was so easy.

I thought i was checking all my code which is ran when entering some page but i forgot one big part and it is constructor:

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
public ProizvodiController(IHostingEnvironment he)
{
    hostingEnvironment = he;
    Program.AbsolutePath = hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
    Debug.FilePath = Path.Combine(Program.AbsolutePath, "Log");
}

public IActionResult Index(int? GrupaID, int? PodgrupaID, int? V, string Pretraga)
{
    ProizvodiModel pm = new ProizvodiModel(GrupaID, PodgrupaID, V, Request);
    pm.Tag = Pretraga;
    return View(pm);
}
```

I forgot that constructor is accessed each time when you access any page from controller and it sets my  `AbsolutePath` variable which i use later.

When i restart my server he lose all in memory data (which is static variable `AbsolutePath`) and it is only set when ANY user enter website but since i call it only in 2 controllers, other controllers were not working.

Solution was to add same code to all controllers constructors.